# Head Swap unable to remove neck line

Tags: texture-painting

I am working on model where I did a head swap using the method (Bridge edge loop -> Merge). After doing that I am trying to match the head and torso texture in photoshop but even matching the texture (I don't know how to call it neck seam or neck line) but I am unable to remove it.

I even tried to clone paint in neck area but the line doesn't go. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, could you please share at least a part of the object (only keep the neck), don't forget to pack the image before saving and use: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Did you tried Smear or Soften in texture painting?

Comment: @moonboots The file size is huge and I have no idea how to compress it. So I will upload it in Mega and I have shared you the link: https://mega.nz/file/kcsiECJZ#wV1IsTb_Y0zchNnhBNgGhobeKsvwrZaR1TU9t0KCAOc

Comment: @MikoCG Yep I tried to smear and soften it but the line doesn't goes away. I dono if it is a bug or something :(

Comment: the 2 parts (top and bottom of the neck) have 2 different materials that have 2 different image textures

Comment: Yea just wanted to say it... select all faces and go to uv editing... is head and body uv connected or not? Because if not it cant be smeared together

Comment: It's a bit trash but you could quickly fix this with the Clone brush, you say that it doesn't work, I'm not sure why

Comment: @MikoCG Before joining the head and torso with CTRL+J I have assigned the correct UV names for head and body. So I guess the body and head UV's are connected.

Comment: @moonboots Here is this pic when I tried to clone paint in solid mode it looks fine but after saving the texture and viewing it in render mode the line doesn't goes away. Mega Link: https://mega.nz/folder/9FcxCSbB#DWXaQSKW7bfBbGlrB-XAAw

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually edit the texture map in photoshop or in texture paint and if necessary also manually change normals